# Draw Mountain Chart android

Tags: android, charts, draw, gradient

I want to draw a mountain chart for my app. The chart have a line on the top, below the line is filled with gradient color. It looks like as this link [enter link description here](http://www.optionshouse.com/faq/android-app/how-can-i-change-the-chart-type-in-the-quote-screen/). Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Which charting tool are you using? 
I have done the same with achartengine like this:
xySeriesRenderer.setFillBelowLine(true);

Comment: I am also using achartengine, but how i can fill field below line with gradient color??

Comment: Dan Dromereschi says that "Gradient is only supported by the range bar chart" at [link](http://groups.google.com/group/achartengine/browse_thread/thread/2a4853b48acd114?pli=1)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve that is using a charting component for Android which supports your needs. The one I know is [TeeChart for Android](http://www.steema.com/teechart/mobile) from [Steema Software](http://www.steema.com/), the company I work for. It supports Area series with gradients. You can see some examples at the TeeChart Mobile -> Android section in the [gallery](http://www.steema.com/gallery/charts/4). A fully functional evaluation version can be downloaded [here](http://www.steema.com/evaluation/java). A simple code snippet to do that would be:

```
    tChart1.getAspect().setView3D(false);
    Area series = new Area(tChart1.getChart());
    series.fillSampleValues();
    series.getGradient().setVisible(true);
```